# Inserting a node to the last of a linkedlist

Tags: c++

I was trying to insert a node to the last of my linkedlist however the code didn't work it just prints nothing.

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>

class node {
    public:
    int data;
    node* next = NULL;
};


class linkedlist {
    public:
    void insertbegin(int new_data);
    void insertmiddle(node* preve_node, int new_data);
    void insertlast(int new_data);
    void print() {
        node* start = headref;

        while (start != NULL) {
            cout << "Our memeber variable is that: " << start->data << endl;
            start = start->next;
        }
    }

    private:
    node* headref = NULL;
};

void linkedlist :: insertbegin(int new_data) {
    node* hen = new node();                                               
    hen->data= new_data;

    if (headref == NULL) {
        headref = hen; 
    }
    else {
       hen->next = headref;
       headref = hen;
    }
}

void linkedlist :: insertlast(int new_data) {
    node* ram = new node();
    ram->data = new_data;
    ram->next = NULL;

    node* ra = headref;

    while (ra != NULL) {
        ra = ra->next;
    }
      
    ra->next = ram;
}

int main() {
    linkedlist link;

    link.insertlast(29);
    link.insertlast(11);
    link.insertlast(38);
    link.insertlast(12);

    link.print();
}
```

I was expecting to code to print 29, 11, 38, 12 in this exact order but the code outputs nothing right now.

Comment: When you use a debugger, what is the *first* statement that doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: `while (ra != NULL) { ra = ra->next; } ra->next = ram;` <- see the problem? Hint: `ra` will _always_ be a null pointer when you dereference it after the loop.

Comment: A couple of things: First of all `NULL` is the old C-compatible macro for null-pointers, in C++ use `nullptr` instead. Secondly, I recommend you also keep a `tailref` that points to the last node of the list, always. Then it's trivial to add a node at the end.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is bad practice, but having it _before_ you include `<iostream>` should be giving you a warning at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of issues with your code have been identified in comments, but the core problem you're asking about lies with your `linkedlist::insertlast()` member function:

> ```
> void linkedlist :: insertlast(int new_data) {
>     node* ram = new node();
>     ram->data = new_data;
>     ram->next = NULL;
>
>     node* ra = headref;
>
>     while (ra != NULL) {
>         ra = ra->next;
>     }
>      
>     ra->next = ram;
> }
> ```

Because your `while` loop iterates while `ra` is *not* `NULL`, it ensures `ra` *must be* `NULL` on exiting the loop. You then dereference it and assign to a member via a `NULL` pointer. This results in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/).

One potential outcome is a segmentation fault. When I compile and run your code, this is the behavior I see. But with undefined behavior, this is not guaranteed.

You should instead first check if the list is empty. If so, `insertbegin()` will work. If not, then you need to iterate until `ra->next` is `NULL`, and then assign the new node to that pointer:

```
void linkedlist :: insertlast(int new_data) {
    if (headref == NULL) {
        insertbegin(new_data);
    }
    else {
        node* ram = new node();
        ram->data = new_data;
        ram->next = NULL;

        node* ra = headref;

        while (ra->next != NULL) {
            ra = ra->next;
        }
      
        ra->next = ram;
    }
}
```

We might also use a `return` to use a little bit less indentation.

```
void linkedlist :: insertlast(int new_data) {
    if (headref == NULL) {
        insertbegin(new_data);
        return;
    }
    
    node* ram = new node();
    ram->data = new_data;
    ram->next = NULL;

    node* ra = headref;

    while (ra->next != NULL) {
        ra = ra->next;
    }
      
    ra->next = ram;
}
```

Comment: If you use a double-pointer `node**` instead, you don't have to distinquish between empty vs non-empty, eg: `node** ra = &headref; while (*ra != NULL) { ra = &((*ra)->next); } *ra = ram;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau One could also delay the creation of the `node` until the spot where to insert it is found, as in `*ra = new node{new_data};`

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

- Since you are dealing with raw owning pointers, you need to read about the [rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). In particular, your class isn't safe to copy since there will then be two objects owning the same data. Since you also don't destroy the elements in your linked list, it will leak memory. Below there's a simple implementation that allows for move construction and move assignment but forbids copy construction and copy assignment:

  ```cpp
  linkedlist() = default;

  // rule of 5 below:
  linkedlist(const linkedlist&) = delete; // no copy 
  linkedlist(linkedlist&& other) noexcept // move is ok
      : headref(std::exchange(other.headref, nullptr)) {}

  linkedlist& operator=(const linkedlist&) = delete; // no copy
  linkedlist& operator=(linkedlist&& other) noexcept { // move is ok
      std::swap(headref, other.headref); // let "other" call clear()
      return *this;
  }

  ~linkedlist() { clear(); } // clear should free all memory
  ```
- `using namespace std;` and `#include <iostream>` should be done in the reverse order. Preferably, don't do `using namespace std;` at all and absolutely don't do it in the global namespace in header files since that pollutes the global namespace for all the users of your header file.
- Don't use [`NULL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL). It requires that you include an extra header file - and `iostream` that you include is not it. Use [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) instead which is always present and doesn't require that you include anything extra.
- `node` is an implementation detail that does not need to be known outside the `linkedlist` class. Make that a nested/internal class in `linkedlist`.
- `insertlast` is broken and overly complicated:

  ```cpp
  while (ra != NULL) { // This makes sure `ra == NULL` when the loop is done
      ra = ra->next;
  }
  ra->next = ram; // ra == NULL here so you have undefined behavior
  ```

  A simple and correct version would instead make `ram` a pointer to *the pointer* you aim to change and loop for as long as that pointer points at something. When you find one that points at `nullptr`, you've found the place to insert your node:

  ```cpp
  void linkedlist::insertlast(int new_data) {
      node** ram = &headref;
      while (*ram) ram = &(*ram)->next;
      *ram = new node{new_data};
  }
  ```
- `insertbegin` is also a bit too complicated. You could simplify it to:

  ```cpp
  void linkedlist::insertbegin(int new_data) {
      headref = new node{new_data, headref};
  }
  ```
- Any member function that doesn't change the object should be `const` qualified. In this case, your `print` function should be:

  ```cpp
  void print() const;
  ```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E1cY1z1xx)

Comment: Heck, `print` could just be overloading `<<`.

Comment: @Chris Indeed! Why didn't I think of that? :-) [Added](https://godbolt.org/z/3TKqf7Pr7)

Comment: No one is perfect!